# Disable all buttons after I click to one button in FB with FBML

Tags: javascript, facebook, button

I am trying to disable all the input buttons on a page after I click to one of the buttons. The buttons can have different ID/Names so it should be able to disable all ...

I need to take all buttons by TAG-NAME ='input' and the set the propriety: .setDisabled(true)

How can I do this?

I need this to work in Facebook!
The app is made using FBML, and not IFRAME.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at fbjqry? It is a jQuery-like wrapper around FBJS that lets you do this kind of thing more easily: http://code.google.com/p/fbjqry/

Once you load the fbjqry.min.js, you could do the following, for example, to hide all checkboxes:

`jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').css('display','none');`

Or in your case, to disable all the buttons:

`jQuery('input[type=button]').attr('disabled','disabled');`